# What language is better suited for P2P video streaming?

Tags: flash, programming-languages, video-streaming, p2p, skype

I would like to write a Skype like software which allows P2P video/audio streaming. What language is better suited for that?

There are several requirements:

1. Software should be easy to install.
2. It should be easy to program.
3. I want to have access to video information. For example to make a face expression recognition on the fly.
4. It should be free.

I am thinking of Python and Java. Which one would be better? Or may be there is a third choice which is better?

**ADDED**

Flash is an attractive option since users can use their browser in which flash is installed by default and if not, it's easy to install flash. But I do not know if I can have access to video (if I want to do some processing). Moreover, Flash is not free.

Comment: This question is really about "libraries and platforms", not "languages".  A change in title might get you some answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you're interested in is likely to involve somewhat heavy network traffic (for video streaming) and CPU usage (for facial recognition).  Efficiency is therefore going to matter quite a bit in your final product, which implies that you'll want those critical parts to be handled by native code, probably written in C or C++.

On the other hand, you're asking for a language that's easy to program, which is very appropriate while you're experimenting and prototyping.  An expressive language that makes your meaning clear in a small amount of code will help you focus on solving the problems before you, rather than getting bogged down in implementation details.  Python is a very good choice for this.  (As a matter of fact, Python was the development language of several other p2p projects including [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28software%29), [P2P-Next](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P2P-Next), and my own video streaming system.)

Allow me to suggest this approach:

1. Develop your first version in a high level language like Python.
2. Use compiled libraries for video frame processing.  Several major multimedia libraries have python bindings, including [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) and [libavcodec](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/).
3. Once you have a working prototype and are satisfied with your design, consider re-implementing the system in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

I would say flash, because the plugin is widespread, you have a high level language and it already have a API for streaming video, so you do not have to reinvent the wheel in C.